# How Can I save image in database using asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image, webapi

I am working on an API. Everything is getting done smoothly so far, but I have to save images to the database in the API. Scenario, let's say I have a class of **Person** with three properties **{Name, Age, and (byte[])Image}**. How can add the Person's image in the database through API?

```
public IHttpActionResult Create([FromBody] Person person) { }
```

Comment: You need to read about how to upload file using web API first. Then you need to learn about how to store image data in SQL server. Then write code using that learning. If you face and issue in that you ask question here with relevant code and proper explanation of the issue you are facing.

Comment: Are you able to save the Person to the database without the image? Having a field in the database that accepts a byte array should not be a problem.

Comment: @PEK Yes, I am able to save the rest of the Person easily, Only the image gets problematic.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you will need to use `VarBinary` in order to pass the image parameter, like in this example:

```
public static void InsertByteArrayintoSqlDatabase()
{
    string sampleText = "Hello World!";

    byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sampleText);

    using (SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.SQLExpress; 
Initial Catalog=MorganDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
    {
        sqlconnection.Open();

        // create table if not exists 
        string createTableQuery = @"Create Table [MyTable](ID int, [BinData] varbinary(max))";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(createTableQuery, sqlconnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string insertXmlQuery = @"Insert Into [MyTable] (ID,[BinData]) Values(1,@BinData)";

        // Insert Byte [] Value into Sql Table by SqlParameter
        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertXmlQuery, sqlconnection);
        SqlParameter sqlParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BinData", byteData);
        sqlParam.DbType = DbType.Binary;
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Taken from https://morgantechspace.com/2014/05/how-to-store-and-read-byte-array-in-sql-server-using-csharp.html

I do not recommend storing images as they are in the database. Instead, it makes much more sense to store them as files and store their name/path in the database.